# Why does Java documentation not include time complexity?

Tags: java, algorithm

I find it really surprising that the java does not specify any time or space complexities for any of the Collection libraries. Given that garbage collection in java is unpredictable, hence nothing is guaranteed, but isn't it helpful to give a average time complexity at least? What am I missing here?

Comment: If you want to look at time complexities, here's a good reference : http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: Often times if you dig deep enough you can find implementation. From there you can figure it out.

Comment: What makes you say this? I thought the documentation does indeed list the time complexities. The Javadoc for ArrayList seems to do this, as does PriorityQueue.

Comment: They do give time complexities. see [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) for instance.

Comment: One thing is the documentation and other is the implementation. There are several vendors of the Java Virtual Machine (Oracle, IBM, and so on). Each of these vendors you can use different algorithms. As always, follow a specification (which includes a sketch of the documentation, almost always pass without change)

Comment: Or see [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

Comment: Since Java is a portable language, exact implementations on different platforms and/or `JVM`s could differ.

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, part of the reason is because individual collections have different time complexities for methods (for example, a `HashSet` can do O(1) contains, but a `LinkedList` can't.) Specific implementations of the interface should have time complexities in their documentation.

Comment: The comments claiming that time complexity of JDK classes is implementation-specific are wrong. The specification of `ArrayList`, which includes time complexity, binds *all implementations* to this characteristic.

Comment: @DennisMeng yes, I meant each specific implementation should have a time complexity mentioned as it's implementation based on a algorithm is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexities are dependant on how you use the collections, however they generally follow the standard time complexities.  You can find out the time complexity of an array, linked list, tree, or hash map anywhere, but there is no requirement that an implementation follow these complexities.

In short, time complexity is for an ideal machine, not real machine with real implementations, so even if you know the time complexity, the details of the actual use case can be more important.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexities are mostly self-explanatory based on the implementation.  `LinkedList` is going to be constant time to add items to the end, approaching linear to add items in the middle.  `HashMap` is going to be near constant access time, `ArrayList` will be linear, until it needs to grow the array, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are time complexities for the major ones, warnings about methods' performance and references to original works. I think these comments are useful, and big-O's might not always be useful.

I.e. `Arrays.sort(Object[] array)`:

> Implementation note: This implementation is a stable, adaptive,
>   iterative mergesort that requires far fewer than **n lg(n)** comparisons
>   when the input array is partially sorted, while offering the
>   performance of a traditional mergesort when the input array is
>   randomly ordered.  If the input array is nearly sorted, the
>   implementation requires approximately n comparisons.  Temporary
>   storage requirements vary from a small constant for nearly sorted
>   input arrays to n/2 object references for randomly ordered input
>   arrays.
>
> The implementation takes equal advantage of ascending and
>   descending order in its input array, and can take advantage of
>   ascending and descending order in different parts of the the same
>   input array.  It is well-suited to merging two or more sorted arrays:
>   simply concatenate the arrays and sort the resulting array.
>   
>   The implementation was adapted from Tim Peters's list sort for
>   Python ([TimSort - http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt).
>   It uses techiques from Peter McIlroy's "Optimistic
>   Sorting and Information Theoretic Complexity", in Proceedings of the
>   Fourth Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms, pp 467-474,
>   January 1993.

Or `CopyOnWriteArrayList`:

> **This is ordinarily too costly**, but may be *more* efficient 
>   than alternatives when traversal operations vastly outnumber 
>   mutations, and is useful when you cannot or don't want to  synchronize
>   traversals, yet need to preclude interference among  concurrent
>   threads.  The "snapshot" style iterator method uses a  reference to
>   the state of the array at the point that the iterator  was created.
>   This array never changes during the lifetime of the  iterator, so
>   interference is impossible and the iterator is  guaranteed not to
>   throw ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: These notes are not present for all implementations. Example, no such complexity is mentioned for TreeSet or SortedSet.

Comment: `SortedSet` can't have complexity costs, because it's abstract and `TreeSet` has it: "This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic operations `add`, `remove` and `contains`." I do agree that having this explicitly stated in some reference table like it's done in this linked cheat sheet or in C#, could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're talking about.  `HashSet`:

> This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets. Iterating over this set requires time proportional to the sum of the HashSet instance's size (the number of elements) plus the "capacity" of the backing HashMap instance (the number of buckets). Thus, it's very important not to set the initial capacity too high (or the load factor too low) if iteration performance is important.

`ArrayList`:

> The size, isEmpty, get, set, iterator, and listIterator operations run in constant time. The add operation runs in amortized constant time, that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time. All of the other operations run in linear time (roughly speaking). The constant factor is low compared to that for the LinkedList implementation.

Comment: The documentation does not follow a predictable pattern of mentioning this. I find a few of the complexities are mentioned in source code but not in the documentation. And few do not have at all like http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html

Comment: @Lavixu: `SortedSet` is an interface, not an implementation.  It would be nonsensical for it to describe time complexity of methods it doesn't have implementations for.  `TreeSet` has descriptions of its time complexity, however.